# How to ensure a certain NIC in a multihomed system is always used for default route?

Tags: debian, networking

I have a fresh debian installation (Bullseye) with two identical network cards with two separate networks (say 10.0.0.1/24 and 192.168.0.1/24), each with its own WAN routing. Both IP addresses come from DHCP under my control. Switching cables  makes no difference, ens18 always has the lower metric.

How does Debian detemine which network connection to take first?

##### In other words: How to to make sure, it is always the same one, in case it relies on latency of hardware etc.?

I could not find any reliable answer to this question, as network management in debian changed over the years.

Edit: Here's the output of `ip route list`.

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev ens18 proto dhcp metric 100
default via 192.168.0.1 dev ens19 proto dhcp metric 101
10.0.0.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.10 metric 100
192.168.0.0/24 dev ens19 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.10 metric 101
```

Comment: This should be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425924/in-linux-what-metric-has-a-route-with-no-metric

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Linux, what metric has a route with no metric?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425924/in-linux-what-metric-has-a-route-with-no-metric)

Comment: Not sure. I know that metrics define priority. But it seems relying on hardware latency. The first active adapter gets the higher metric!?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The first active adapter gets the lower metric. You are right. Yes, and that's why my question is, how to set the priority manually, surviving a reboot?

Comment: Well, hm… my brain priority is "WHY metric 100, HOW metric 101". Of course, there's latency… sometimes…

Comment: Good question. Regardless of what I linked, I'd suspect 100 is just chosen as the default for first active adapter, next ones get progressively lower priorities. That's how I'd do it anyway. Are the IP addresses static, or do they come from DHCP - if DHCP, is it / are they under your control? Please do add to the question again rather than commenting. I'd also suggest rephrasing the title so it better reflects what you're after.

Comment: It's both via DHCP, as in the command's output. They're both under my control. Switching cables makes no difference. ens18 has always the lower metric.